# ASP.Net / VB to Build Excel Spreadsheet from Access Database

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel

I need to put together a prototype web application to present a user with options from an Access database and use those options to read the same Access database to build and return to them an Excel spreadsheet.

I thought I'd just build Excel macros to do the formatting and invoke those macros from ASP.net, but the more I read the less likely this seems to work. I have plenty of experience in Excel, Access and VB, but it's been around 12 years since I did anything in ASP. It's changed, just a little...

So, toolset would be Windows 7, Office 2010, IIS, Visual Studio 2010 and ... anything else?

Comment: You cannot use Office Interop for this. It doesn't work from a server application. You will be able to read the Access database through the OLEDB database driver, and there are a variety of tools which can create Excel spreadsheets.

Comment: May be of interest http://forum.lessthandot.com/viewtopic.php?f=93&t=3801&p=19808&hilit=excel#p19808  or  http://forum.lessthandot.com/viewtopic.php?f=137&t=3739&p=19558&hilit=excel#p19558 If you need more information, just say.

Comment: Thanks, that helps somewhat. I was afraid it was going to be more involved than just running VBA macros. I need to do some formatting - colouring outliers, that sort of thing - so I don't think the SQL route or the HTML table route will suffice - although I may be wrong and other HTML content may affect appearance. If that's not the case, I'll need to look for an appropriate tool. Any suggestions for a (preferably free) one?